# Using Simulink to record and output audio

Tags: raspbian, audio, matlab, simulink

I'm testing my raspberry pi(setup with a morpheus and cirrus board for audio) and created following model in Simulink:

[image]

I've established proper connection between my host-PC and the pi using an ethernet cable, but whether if I try to Run the model from my host or try to push the software to my hardware, I keep getting a "No Audio Device found" error.

From that point I figured I had to input the audio devices into my host-PC, which was the solve. However what I'm trying to achieve is pushing the model to the pi, having a headset input into the pi and using that as I/O. 
Am I completely off here? Do I need some certain package for other model components, do I need to setup my system in another manner?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to run on the RPi?